# Additional alert emails not working

Tags: email, alert, opencart2.3

i would like to send the notification (or alert) email to additional addresses.
thats what i did:

1. /index.php?route=setting/setting
2. Tab "Email"
3. Add additional emails (comma seperated)

i found a lot of topics about exactly this problem. but the solution always was to change protocol from SMTP to mail(). in my case that's not an option. dose some one know how to get to send the alerts to multiple addresses?

thank you...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Save the following **[VQMOD] Bug fix: "Additional Alert Email" field not sending email issue in Opencart v.2.3.0.2** as `knns_bug_fix_additional_alert_mail_field_not_sending_email_issue_v2302.xml` and upload it to `/vqmod/xml/` folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <modification
    xmlns="https://github.com/vqmod/vqmod"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="https://github.com/vqmod/vqmod https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vqmod/vqmod/master/vqmod.xsd">
    >
        <id><![CDATA[[VQMOD] Bug fix: "Additional Alert Email" field not sending email issue in Opencart v.2.3.0.2]]></id>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
        <vqmver>2.6.3</vqmver>
        <author>kanenas.net (aka Nikolas Branis) - nbran@kanenas.net</author>
        <file path="admin/view/template/setting/" name="setting.tpl" error="log">
            <operation error="skip">
                <search position="replace"><![CDATA[<textarea name="config_mail_alert_email" rows="5" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_mail_alert_email; ?>" id="input-alert-email" class="form-control"><?php echo $config_alert_email; ?></textarea>]]></search>
                <add><![CDATA[
                    <textarea name="config_alert_email" rows="5" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_mail_alert_email; ?>" id="input-alert-email" class="form-control"><?php echo $config_alert_email; ?></textarea>
                ]]></add>
            </operation>
        </file>
    </modification>
```

**Note**: [vQmod](https://github.com/vqmod/vqmod/releases/tag/v2.6.3-opencart) is required!